# How to make Inverted curve or border-radius for div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on one project in which i have to style a border of a div inverted to achieve this i can only use css and js i cannot use any plugins.
I have gone through several online posts and similar looking questions on stack but couldnt really find what i want , I am attaching a [image] for reference as well as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fsc0orL/) of what i have tried so far.

```css
.outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid #888;
}
.inner i {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.inner .top {
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.inner .bottom {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: -22px;
}
.inner .left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.inner .right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
.content {
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <i class="top left"></i>
    <i class="top right"></i>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <i class="bottom right"></i>
    <i class="bottom left"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've did this, maybe it can help you http://jsfiddle.net/7fsc0orL/2/

Comment: This looks like the circle in the middle is a layer on top of the layer below. Meaning, it looks like an image on top of what's behind. so I don't see any point in creating an inverse border-radius which is on it's own a problematic subject, it's not supported well in browsers and there are different ways of achieving that effect, the best way is to use an image.

Comment: how can i use circle image with borders cut in between ?

Answer (score 1):

Am sure This will help you

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mxehp3sh/2/

HTML

```
   <div id="a" class="circle-border">B</div>
```

CSS

```
    body{background:yellow;}
  .circle-border {margin:10px;
  display: inline-block;    
position: relative;    
height: 100px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
vertical-align: middle;
 }

 #a {
width: 90%;
border-left: none;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(
    100% 50%,
    circle closest-corner, 
    transparent 0,
    transparent 55px, 
    transparent  56px, 
    grey 57px 
);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(100% 50%, circle closest-corner, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55px, transparent  56px, grey 57px);
background-image: -ms-radial-gradient(100% 50%, circle closest-corner, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55px, transparent  56px, grey 57px);
background-image: -o-radial-gradient(100% 50%, circle closest-corner, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55px, transparent  56px, grey 57px);
background-image: radial-gradient(100% 50%, circle closest-corner, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 55px, transparent  56px, grey 57px);
}
```

Comment: + 1 for the effort but im supporting ie 8 , this thing wont work in ie 8 and 9 so still to find right answer.